# 504 Gateway Timeout after loading custom JS in wordpress in Functions.php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I wish to ask for help in respect of loading a custom JS file in the functions.php file. I currently have the following in the functions.php (Child theme):

```
<?php

function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style';

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( $parent_style ), wp_get_theme()->get('Version'));

    wp_enqueue_style('jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css');

}

function wp_adding_scripts() {

    wp_register_script('app.js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/app.js', array(), '', true);

    wp_enqueue_scripts('app.js');

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles');

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_adding_scripts');

?>
```

This is currently in my app.js file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

alert('call');

});
```

When i load my website, i’m getting a 504 gateway timeout. The backend loads fine (I.e. plugins, appearance, etc).  I am not getting anything in the console (I presume as its not loading the page at all?).

My choice of JS file content is to test that it is loading the file.

If i remove the reference to the app.js out of the functions file, the website loads fine, but unfortunately no custom javascript is available.

Please let me know if there is anything further I can provide.

Edit:

Ok i've modified it to as follows (Please let me know if etiquette is to paste it in full, just shown modified part):

```
function wp_adding_scripts_bnyxwshpit() {

wp_register_script('app_amesmvzuoy.js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/app_hrlobpnygg.js', array('jquery'), '', true);

wp_enqueue_scripts('app_amesmvzuoy.js');
```

}

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles');

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_adding_scripts_bnyxwshpit');
```

Interestingly, in php_errorlog (In /public_html), i'm getting the following error:

> PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in
>   phar:///chroot/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/bin/wp-cli.phar/php/WP_CLI/FileCache.php
>   on line 265

The debug.log file has not logged anything (Apart from when i entered jquery into the array dependency without apostrophes).

Cpanel error log:

> [Mon Mar 26 08:44:40.640027 2018] [:notice] [pid 56696] [client
>   165.225.81.57:57752] mod_hive matched URI http://www.knowthelanguage.co.uk/wp-login.php
>   (/home/knowthe8/public_html/wp-login.php) with match 2, referer:
>   https://www.knowthelanguage.co.uk/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.knowthelanguage.co.uk%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
>
> [Mon Mar 26 08:45:42.079235 2018] [:warn] [pid 53633] [client
>   165.225.81.57:33380] Timeout waiting for output from CGI script /home/knowthe8/public_html/index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have name collision somewhere?

I would try the following:

1. Try renaming `wp_adding_scripts()` to something unique ([use random.org for instance](https://www.random.org/strings/?num=10&len=10&loweralpha=on&unique=on&format=html&rnd=new)) like `wp_adding_scripts_tkpirpzivx()`
2. Rename the script handle `app.js` to something unique, e.g. `app.js.uwprrjopmo`
3. Check the return value from `wp_register_script`. See the [WP doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/):

   > (bool) Whether the script has been registered. True on success, false on failure.
4. Activate `WP_DEBUG` (constant in your `wp-config.php`, [see more info here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)) and add some "checkpoints" using PHP built-in function `error_log("i'm here");`. Note that your error log file is located in `/wp-content/debug.log`

Good luck!

Comment: OK - I've renamed the function name, the .js filename, and the script handle.  I've included "return $registered" in the function to add the script with no luck.  I'm looking at the debugging built-in function now.  I can add to my original question what i've updated the code to, if that helps?

Appreciate your time on this :)

Comment: Of course, update your answer with any relevant information you have! It may help.

Comment: In `wp_adding_scripts_bnyxwshpit`, if you add an `error_log("trying to add scripts")`, does it appears in `debug.log`?

Comment: Managed to solve it.  There are two parts - there was a type (wp_enqueue_scripts).  Additionally this theme has a enqueue.php file, where the scripts in relation to the theme are enqueue'd.  Not sure if this is normal practice with other themes, as first i'd seen it from googling round extensively.

Will look to identify if its in the child theme or parent theme this needs to be placed into.

Appreciate the help Indigo.